# ANDROID Best way to load dynamic preference

Tags: android, json, sharedpreferences

I am creating an application who show a scool time table . The user need to choose his establishement,formation, group. But there no the same groups for each formations and each establishments.
E.g:
Establishement 1
 -formation 1
  -group 1
  -group 2
 - formation 2
  -group A
  -group B
  -..
Establishement 2
[..]

So to load preference I have trying to use AsyncTask to get 3 JSON from server : establishment and when the user choose the Establishement it get JSON of formation ...
But the Asynctask is too slow and crash the app if the user click on preference list before the end of the load.
So My question : How can I optimize this ? (not with the code but with a new method)
Thanks for reading me.
Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a ProgressDialog to the Activity so until your data is loaded the user will be unable to click on anything. After the data is loaded you can call progressDialog.dismiss()

Comment: So I need to load all formations and groups of all establishment even although the user will choose 1 establishment ?

Comment: No, what I meant is when user chooses establishment/group/formation a ProgressDialog is shown until the data is received from the server. After the data is received you can dismiss the ProgressDialog. Then when user choses the next option the same process is carried out again. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, you gave me an idea, and it works. I have set "setenable" to "false" until load is finish :D

Answer (score 1):

You don't let them click on anything until your data is loaded.  Put up a loading screen, do the AsyncTask, then remove the loading screen and go to your real app when its done.